# MahApps panoram control not displaying photo's

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I want use the MahApps PanoramaControl to display a bunch of photo's. However I see only the string paths appear in the control, which will be correct if you look at my code. 
But I can't figure out howto get it working to show the images instead of the links.

Xaml:

```
    <Controls:Panorama Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                   ItemBox="140"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
  string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Google Drive\Images\Backgrounds");

  test = new PanoramaGroup("My Photo's", filePaths);
  PhotoCollection = new ObservableCollection<PanoramaGroup> { test };
```

Anyone an idea on how to make it show the images? The control is load as I can scroll sideways on the text. 
There is not much documentation on their site on how to get it working...

Or are you using some other Metro style lib for the 4.0 framework?

[image: panorama control]

Answer (score 2):

In order to get MahApps Panorama control i would offer the follow solution below. As to other frameworks that provide this level of detailed MODERN UI experience I have not come across any but interested to know if you do.

Hope the solutions works for you.

You need to add a Data Template the represent the object you're showing.

Start off by defining the object in a POCO class (as illustrated below). Then in the population of the items ensure you translate them to the newly created POCO object instead of leaving them as string values.

```
public class Photo {
   public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Next in the definition of you XAML window you need to create a reference to the namespace where the POCO object resides.

```
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:project.models;assembly=project"
```

Last, but not least, you want to then create a DataTemplate to represent the object. This is added to the window resources.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Photo}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This should then let the render take place in the interface where it belongs. Hope this works for you.

Comment: DataTemplates are the key to this. Without specifying one, and the DataType and layout it needs, the control will just .ToString() an object it doesn't recognise - which is what you're seeing above.